# <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h> not found

Tags: objective-c, foundation

No matter I use clang, gcc, llvm or cmake, as long as there is this line in the project:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/Corefoundation.h>
```

The terminal will show error

> CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h not found

I used to compile objective-c code including this line on terminal well. But the weird problem occurred since my Mac updated to Mojave.

Anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: Mojave is beta software. Anything could be broken.

Comment: `“#import CoreFoundation/CoreFoubdation.h “` Is it because of the typo?

Comment: @Chris I typed angular bucket < in the question, but contents between the buckets can not be shown. I have to remove it.

Comment: @Koen tomorrow I’ll try on my another Mac to see if it’s issue of version.

Comment: I also tried export PATH=“System/Library/Frameworks:$PATH”, or export PATH=“/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/...:$PATH” but no magic happens.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that it says “CoreFoubdation.h” with a ‘b’. I’m not sure exactly what your reply is saying. I never said anything about contents between any buckets.

Comment: Yosemite works fine.